# Why this anonymous method does not work while the lambda does?

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

I am learning anonymous methods, lambdas etc. and cannot find the reason why it does not work here:

```
// this does not work
MyDictionary.Keys.Where(delegate(string s) { s.Length == 5; });

// this works
MyDictionary.Keys.Where(w => w.Length == 5);
```

Comment: Statement lambdas, like anonymous methods, cannot be used to create expression trees.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Correct but not relevant here. This question would use `Enumerable.Where` (taking a delegate), not `Queryable.Where` (taking an expression tree).

Comment: "does not work here" is not enough information. You should *always* include the error message you're getting.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the result of statement:

```
MyDictionary.Keys.Where(delegate(string s) { return s.Length == 5; });
```

Think about `delegate` as a complete method which have to be as same as possible to an independent method, except the naming part. So, you can imagine it as:

```
delegate(string s) {
    // you would need to return something here:
    return s.Length == 5; 
}
```

UPDATE:

Also, think about these 2 lambdas:

```
MyDictionary.Keys.Where(w => w.Length == 5); // works
MyDictionary.Keys.Where(w => { w.Length == 5 }); // does not work
```

Why the second one is not working? Think this way to getting a better vision of what's happening. It's just about simplifying the picture:

The first lambda is a statement: `w.Length == 5` and a statement has a result which returns it actually. Doesn't?

But the second one: `{ w.Length == 5 }` is a block. And a block does not return anything, except you explicitly do it.

Comment: The second sample lambda doesn't compile. The mechanism here is not  the difference expression vs block by itself, but a special lambda rule that treats bare expressions differently.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `The second sample lambda doesn't compile` -> I mentioned that by `does not work`. The rest: Thanks to the point, I'm just trying to simplify the picture. I'm a teacher, and in my experience most people, needs a clean and simple picture to start understanding. Thanks again.

Comment: It just misses a `;` (to compile but still not work).

Comment: You mean `s => { s.Length == 5; }`? It has a compile time error and won't compile, you can try it. The only way to compile is `s => { return s.Length == 5; }`

Comment: You're right, that still fails to compile. But with a more meaningful error than "; expected".

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a `return` statement in the body of the delegate, like this:

```
MyDictionary.Keys.Where(delegate(string s) { return s.Length == 5; });
```

You can thing as the `return` being kind of implied by the arrow in the lambda version, that's why it is working.

Comment: It is implied, but not by the arrow. When you write `w => {w.Length == 5;}` you have the same problem.